# Finding identical polygons based on some attribute and then calculating field based on other attributes using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a polygon feature class and its corresponding attribute table that relates all silviculture treatments on USFS lands across the western United States:

[image]

The image above relates a sample of the attribute table for the polygon feature class described above. These entries contain equivalent values for `“SUID”`, `“FACTS_ID”` and two entries, `“OBJECTID” = 510` and `“OBJECTID” = 512`, have equivalent values for the attribute field `“ACTIVITY_CODE”`.

`“SUID”` relates a discrete polygon that is effectively a discrete management unit. Specific actions on that spatial unit will only have consequence for my investigation if a certain amount of time has passed before an additional treatment has been executed. For example, `“OBJECTID” = 510` and `“OBJECTID” = 512` describe two `“Patch Clearcut”` treatments that only occurred a year apart. I need to interrogate how much time has passed between the same treatments on the same unit of land.

Logically: IF “SUID” AND “FACTS_ID” AND “ACTIVITY_CODE” are equivalent for any number of entries, determine the absolute value of the difference between the two years that the events occurred.

Comment: I think that's just a summary statistics tool grouping by your 3 fields “SUID”, “FACTS_ID” AND “ACTIVITY_CODE” and getting the min and max of your date field for which you can then determine the time period elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Dissolve. Calculate Statistic: Range.